# Unable to access subdirectories off user home directory when logging in via SSH

Tags: terminal, ssh

When logging into a Mac with SSH remote-access enabled, I'm unable to access files in `~/Desktop`, `~/Documents`, and the like. For example, after logging in, I can do `cd Desktop` but then running `ls` returns `ls: .: Operation not permitted`.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively to Andreas' answer, in modern operating systems you also have a tick box in...

`System Preferences > Sharing > Remote Login > Allow full disk access for remote users`

Comment: Actually I would assume that ticking off that box should be enough.

Comment: @nohillside Yes, it does the same thing and adds the `sshd-keygen-wrapper` to the Privacy pane, just easier to find and know.  I've edited "additionally" to "alternatively", if that is a better expression.

Answer (score 3):

Go to **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy**. Then go to either **Files and Folders** or **Full Disk Access** and set up `sshd-keygen-wrapper` with the desired permissions.